# Extract json object to .yml translation file on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I have json object as below

```
  {
  'questions.new': 'New Question',
  'questions.other.recent': 'Recent',
  'questions.other.old': 'Old'
  }
```

I need to write this data to .yml file by using Ruby on Rails method.
My expected file is as below

```
en:
  questions:
    new: 'New Question'
    other:
      recent: 'Recent'
      old: 'Old'
```

Can someone help me on this task, thanks so much!

Comment: Tell us what've you tried already?

Comment: is that your final json structure.

Comment: check this gem(https://github.com/mislav/gorgeous), this will do the data format conversion. but your json should be in particular format.